# Disable certain buttons depending on which user has logged in

Tags: c#, windows, forms, button, authentication

In login form, When I login as Jack which exist in the DOCTOR table, it will go to page_two. I want to disable nurse button 1, and nurse button 2 since Jack is not a nurse but a doctor. Then for the opposite, if I login as Mary, which exist in the NURSE table, it will go to page_two. I want to disable doctor button 1, and doctor button 2 since Mary is not a doctor but a nurse.

The button names for Page_two is btnDoctor1, btnDoctor2, btnNurse1 and btnNurse2

**//login Form codes**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GRP_02_03_SACP
{
    public partial class page_one : Form
    {
        public page_one()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void page_one_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandtext = "SELECT dUsername, dPassword from DOCTOR";
            // Add a WHERE Clause to SQL statement
            strCommandtext += "   WHERE dUsername=@dname AND dPassword=@dpwd;";
            strCommandtext += "SELECT nUsername, nPassword from NURSE WHERE nUsername=@nname AND nPassword=@npwd;";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandtext, myConnect);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dname", textUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dpwd", txtPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nname", textUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@npwd", txtPassword.Text);


            try
            {
                // STEP 3: open connection and retrieve data by calling ExecuteReader
                myConnect.Open();
                // STEP 4: Access Data
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                while (reader.Read()) //For Doctor
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Login Successful") == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        page_two form = new page_two();
                        form.Show();
                        return;
                    }                                     
                } 
                reader.NextResult();
                while (reader.Read()) //For Nurse
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Login Successful") == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        page_two form = new page_two();
                        form.Show();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                //STEP 5: close connection
                reader.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                //STEP 5: close connection
                myConnect.Close();
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: use `form.nursebtn.Visible = False;` when you create form instance.

Comment: Ok but If i wan to login as doctor which is jack, but how about if I want to pop out a access denied message when nursebutton is clicked? @Al-3sli

Comment: you can create public variable to hold permeation type if it's doctor set it 1 else 2 , something like this :    `permeationtype = 1;` that indicate that this user is doctor so when the user press nursebutton you can check  permeationtype if it's 1 then show your message else continue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create some `Person` class to hold person data:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public JobPosition Position { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

Where `Position` is a enum for job positions available for your persons:

```
public enum JobPosition
{
    Doctor,
    Nurse
}
```

Next step will be separating data access logic from presentation code by moving database queries to some repository class:

```
public class PersonRepository
{
    public Person GetPerson(string userName, string password)
    {
        // execute query and create Person instance
    }
}
```

Also I'd create separate login form which should be shown before your main form starts. It should use `PersonRepository` to get `Person` instance which should be passed to `MainForm` constructor:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    return;

Application.Run(new MainForm(loginForm.Person));
```

On main form use position of logged in person to enable or disable controls:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private Person _person;

    public MainForm(Person person)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _person = person;
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fooButton.Enabled = (_person.Position == JobPosition.Doctor);
        // etc
    } 
}
```